# SQL- count the non NULL values and count the rows that has string "1"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count non null row in a column but it's counting all the rows and and count the rows in a column that has string "1".
I was able to count the rows in a column that has string "1" for the 1st column but on the 2nd one, it's count the "0" too.
I've seen some articles here but it didn't resolved the issue.

```
SELECT NAME as Agent_Name, COUNT(case when Thumbs_Up= 1 then 1 else null end) as Thumbs_Up, 
   COUNT(case when No_Solution_Found =1 then 1 else null end) as No_Solution,
   COUNT(case when Save is null then 0 else 1 end) as Total_Saves,
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY NAME
```

Table:

```
Name      | Thumbs_up | No_Solution_Found | Save
Jonathan  | 1         | 0                 | Saved  
Mike      | 0         | 1                 | Null    
Peter     | 1         | 0                 | Null  
Mike      | 1         | 0                 | Saved
Peter     | 0         | 1                 | Saved
Mike      | 1         | 0                 | Saved
Peter     | 0         | 1                 | Saved
```

Expected results:

```
Name      | Thumbs_up | No_Solution       | Total_Save
Jonathan  | 1         | 0                 | 1
Mike      | 2         | 1                 | 2
Peter     | 1         | 2                 | 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `SUM` instead of `COUNT`

```
SELECT NAME as Agent_Name, 
   SUM(case when Thumbs_Up = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Thumbs_Up, 
   SUM(case when No_Solution_Found =1 then 1 else 0 end) as No_Solution,
   SUM(case when Save is null then 0 else 1 end) as Total_Saves,
 FROM table 
 GROUP BY NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Since only the `Save` column has `NULL`s, I assume that's the column you have the problem with.

In your query you wrote:

> ```
> COUNT(case when Save is null then 0 else 1 end) as Total_Saves,
> ```

That is, you're replacing `NULL` by `0`, which is a non null value and therefore is counted.

You presumable wanted to just write:

```
COUNT(Save) as Total_Saves
```

(And BTW, there is a comma after `as Total_Saves` in your query, that doesn't belong there, as no other column expression follows.)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query-:

```
Select 
Name,
sum(Thumbs_up),
sum(No_Solution_Found),
count(case when [Save] is not null then 1 else null end) as Total_save 
from TABLE 
group by Name
```

SQL Server 2014